# How do i manually upload an image to web2py filesystem without using forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, web2py

Currently I have a `div` that has `input` fields of either type `text` or `file` dynamically added through `jQuery.append()`. There are a few buttons with JavaScript onclick methods to control this. I have a "publish" button that calls `$.ajax()` to send input values to my web2py controller function.

js publish code:

```
var publish = function(){
   //extract element data and classify as image or not
   var elem_data = [];  
   for( var i = 0; i < elem_count; i++ ){
       var e = document.getElementById('elem'+i);
       elem_data.push({
           value: e.value,
           image: (e.type == "file")
       });
   }

   //creata data Obj and attach title
   var send_data = {
       title: document.getElementById('title').value,
       body: elem_data
   };

   //ajax call sending data to default/create
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'create',
       data: {data: JSON.stringify(send_data)},
       success: function(data){
          $('#new'+new_count).html(data);
       }
   }); 
}
```

This is all working. One strange thing i did note though is that if i `document.getElementById().value` one of the file inputs the filename is prefixed by C:/fakepath/

Anyway, the form data is successfully sent to the controller function (text displays properly, but file values are still prefixed by fakepath). My question is how do I upload the file to the filesystem and the reference to the DB?

I have tried the following in my controller function but for some reason it throws an expected string or buffer on the `json.loads()`.

```
data = json.loads(request.vars['data'])
for b in data['body']:
    if (b['image']):
        img = db.image.img.store(b['value'])
        db.image.insert(img = img)
```

Replacing the last two lines with:

```
session.flash = b['value']
```

flashes `C:\fakepath\file.ext` to the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: `C:\fakepath\...` shows up on webkit browsers. On internet explorer it should show the real path.

Comment: yeah i have read that its a browser security thing. i don't mind if it doesn't show me the path, but why is the upload/db insertion not working?

Comment: you can't upload a file by simply taking the value of the input...doesn't work that way. Do web search for ajax upload